# Looking for a simple GUI for variants of chess

Tags: engines, chess-variants, programming

I am currently coding an engine for a variant of chess called [Monster Chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_chess). I was wondering if there a GUI existed that would simply take pieces from a square to another (eg e4 to e5) without considering the legality of the move or whose turn it was, since in Monster Chess white gets two plies for every ply black gets, and white can temporarily move into check.

Comment: You may find this interesting https://www.facebook.com/DagazGames/ This guy has created a lot of engine-powered GUI-enabled chesslike games. It's an open-source project.

Answer (score 1):

The chessboard editor at https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/ has two modes selected by radio buttons: "position setup" and "legal moves only". In position setup you can do anything on the board including adding or removing chessmen.